# Why does HTTP client sends empty data in the ACK message of the three-way handshake?

Tags: sockets, wireshark

I am using Wireshark, and I note that my browser connects a website, it sends an empty ACK packet (and  not an ACK packet with an http request).
Why does it happends? In TCP and HTTP RFCs it is not forbid to send ACK packets with data. Can a delayed ACK be implemented here?

Also, is there a way to enable/disable sending an ACK with data in  socket programming?

Note: it is seems to be that an ACK packet can be send with data (see https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/36023/tcp-3-way-handshake-data-in-third-message). Still, I am wondering how can force it. 
[image]

Comment: What browser is it? And isn't this more of a Super User or Server Fault question?

Comment: It just means that the browser creates the connection and for some reason takes enough time to fhen send the request that it doesn't get piggybacked on the ACK.

Comment: Chrome. Is it the ACK by default is piggybacked?

Comment: If the first data is sent soon enough after the connect it will be piggybacked. This also relates to the Nagle algorithm (TCP_NODELAY).

Comment: It is really weird that it takes too much time to send a request.

Comment: @user207421 From Wikipedia, it seems that Nagle algorithm sends immediately an 
 ACKwith no data  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sending an empty ACK as part of the TCP handshake is actually more common then already including data in the final part of the TCP handshake.

The typical client code first calls [connect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) and only after this returns successfully it sends the data. `connect` will only return successfully if the server has responded with SYN+ACK. The kernel will automatically issue an ACK for this to signal to the server that the handshake is now completed. The kernel does not have any application data to send at this point so it cannot include these data into this ACK.

Just imagine what would happen if the final ACK would be deferred to wait for more potential data from the client: in the worst case the client would not send such data because it waits for data from the server first - which is typical for protocols like SMTP, FTP, ... . But since the server does not get the ACK from the client it would not consider the TCP handshake complete and thus would not send any data. This would therefore introduce an unnecessary delay until the client decides to send the empty ACK anyway.

Thus, in order to optimize the handshake the client has to tell the kernel that it will immediately start sending data and that the kernel should not send its ACK already. This can at least in Linux be done with the `TCP_QUICKACK` option:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_QUICKACK, False)
s.connect(("example.com",80))
s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n")
print(s.recv(1024))
```

With `TCP_QUICKACK` explicitly set to False the ACK of the TCP handshake already transports application data:

```
IP local-system.45664 > example.com.http: Flags [S], seq 1590101890, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4226937632 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP example.com.http > local-system.45664: Flags [S.], seq 3649111496, ack 1590101891, win 65535, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 625701214 ecr 4226937632,nop,wscale 9], length 0
IP local-system.45664 > example.com.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:38, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4226937765 ecr 625701214], length 37: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Without explicitly setting the option one get the empty ACK:

```
IP local-system.45856 > example.com.http: Flags [S], seq 4147534093, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 4227186296 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP example.com.http > local-system.45856: Flags [S.], seq 123501506, ack 4147534094, win 65535, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 2369778695 ecr 4227186296,nop,wscale 9], length 0
IP local-system.45856 > example.com.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4227186421 ecr 2369778695], length 0
IP local-system.45856 > example.com.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:38, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 4227186421 ecr 2369778695], length 37: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: But why is it common? Should Nagle algorithm piggyback the data?

Comment: @user3563894: You only consider applications where the client is the first one sending data. In many protocols this is not the case and thus waiting for client data would introduce a delay. See my updated answer for a more extensive explanation.

Comment: I totally understand why the client sends an empty packet case SMTP and for FTP. But in HTTP the client sends first the request.

Comment: @user3563894: And how does the TCP stack know this? Nothing in `connect` says that the client will start sending data immediately after this, which means that the kernel should better send an empty Ack.

Comment: So how can we enable such thing? Why not to consider it as an option?

Comment: Note: it can be done in TCP (see https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/36023/tcp-3-way-handshake-data-in-third-message) I wounder how it can be done.

Comment: @user3563894: see updated answer - setting `TCP_QUICKACK` makes it possible on Linux to optimize the handshake